# Почему не выводит нужное число?

Tags: java

```
public class Solution {
    public static double addTenPercent(int i) {
       double c = i * 10 / 100;
       double p = i + c;
       return p;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(addTenPercent(9));
    }
}
```

Comment: А какое число ннннадо?

Comment: Должно к заданному числу прибавить 10% от этого числа

Comment: То есть должно быть 9.9

Comment: можно вот так сделать addTenPercent(double i)

Comment: Не не, в том то и прикол

Comment: Что надо, чтоб было int

Comment: Но уже решил, сделал 100.0 и заработало

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите получить результат типа `double`, то в выражении стоит использовать соответсвующие значения (хотя бы одно):

```
public static double addTenPercent(int i) {
   double c = i * 10.0 / 100;
   double p = i + c;
   return p;
}
```

В противном случае сначала считается выражение `i * 10 / 100` работая с целыми числами, и лишь после получения результата происходит его кастинг к типу `double`.

Comment: Сделал 100.0 - заработало, не знаю почему

Comment: Не скажете почему?

Comment: Последнее предложение в ответе :)